# How to update a list item from one list to another using a 2010 workflow in SP Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have two lists. The List 1(tasks) has a drop down field that when set to In Progress creates an entry on List 2(suggestions). If any of the entries on List 1 change to Final status the corresponding item on List 2 needs to update.

I saw a previous answer to a question like this:"When you create item in list 2 keep a lookup column pointing to ID for list1. So when any changes are made to list 1, search for the item in List 2 with column values as List1_ID. This approach will work if you have only 1 item in list2 corresponding to list1."

If this is the correct answer then can someone provide me with screen shots to walk me through this? If it is not the correct answer can someone provide one? I would still need an example please.

Comment: While it doesn't help you with your problem directly, I recommend to overthink using 2010 workflows. Support is going do be dropped by M$ in the future. If you have access to PowerAutomate I recommend to use a Flow instead. A Flow could solve that issue easily.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** I hope you know that there exists an ID column in every list which has unique ID for every new item created.

See as follows:

[image]

**2.** Now our task would be as follows for List2:

Create a column in SharePoint List 2(suggestions) to store this item Id from List 1 using a 2010 workflow from SPD. This workflow should run every item a new item is created in List 1. So you will have to update this column in List 2 using a Wrokflow. (only after you created list item in List 2)

Now whenever You wish to update the item in second list, you can use the :

**Update List item** Action

--> So afterwards we need something from both the lists for using this action( as you mentioned a lookup ) :

[image]

--> Here in the screenshot over the bottom, the **item id** is the column we had created in the 1st step( in List 2) and Current Item:ID is the column from List 1. That means this workflow should run on item change event over the first workflow.

This way both the lists will stay related and associated and based on ID's you can easily update items in second list. This is similar to foreign key relations in Relational Database, if you are aware about Database concepts.